# How to select first img tag in a div with many img tag?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have this html :

```
<div class="image">
   <img src=... />
   <img src= .../>
</div>
```

And I would to apply css only to the first image of div of class image without having to add a class to my first img (in that case, I would do `.image .img1` but is there another way ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the `:first-child` selector to do this.

You could also use `:nth-child(1)`  (where the 1 is = to the first child, 2 is equal to the second child etc.)

Finally, a more proper way would be the use of `:first-of-type`

For example:

```
div.image img:first-child {}
```

Or:

```
div.image img:nth-child(1) {}
```

Or (if there are other elements, say an `<h1>` that comes prior to any images:

```
div img:first-of-type
```

If you have the potential for having a div with class image which has images inside it and also another div which has images in it, like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image">
   <img src=... />
   <img src= .../>
   <div class="image">
      <img src=... />
      <img src= .../>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then use these selectors:

For example:

```
div.image > img:first-child {}
```

Or:

```
div.image > img:nth-child(1) {}
```

Or:

```
div > img:first-of-type
```

Documentation on [:first-child](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:first-child) and on [:nth-child()](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:nth-child) and on [:first-of-type](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:first-of-type) and on [child combinator](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/combinators/child).

Note that `:nth-child()` and `:first-of-type` are CSS3 selectors, which carry some limited support when using IE.  See [Can I use CSS3 Selectors](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) for browser support details.

Consider something like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to help standardize IE.

Comment: In what way is `:first-of-type` better than `:first-child` if all the children are going to be `img` elements?

Comment: Edited my answer.  In any case, first-of-type would be a better solution overall as it is more specific to the img tag only.  If at any point this HTML is modified to include, for example a heading before the images (which wouldn't be an unreasonable idea), :first-child would break, and the solution would be to use :first-of-type to fix.  Why not just cut to the chase and use :first-of-type in the first place?  No reason that I can see not to.

Comment: "limited support when using IE" would count as one. Also, Modernizr does not polyfill selector support - you do that with Selectivizr instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using `first-child` selector

```
.image img:first-child
{
  height:500px;
  width:200px;
  border:15px solid Red;    
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sAFAm/)

Answer (score 4):

The ':first-child' selector seems like it might be what you need.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you want the first image inside a DIV (and there might be other elements preceding it) you need `first-of-type` rather than `first-child`

```
div > img:first-of-type {}
```

consider the following **html**

```
<div>
    <p>paragraph, this is :first-child</p>
    <img src="..."><!-- this is img:first-of-type -->
</div>
```

More details can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-of-type

Answer (score 2):

```css
article>img:first-child {
   border:1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<article class="image">
   <img src=... />
   <img src= .../>
   <div class="image">
      <img src=... />
      <img src= .../>
      <img src= .../>
            
   </div>
   <img src= .../>
      <img src= .../>
</div>
```