# How do I differentiate between two different images in the same class in my CSS file

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to add two images on either side of my header. The issue is that I use the img  selector for the image that's already to the left of my text and that specifies the positioning. I need another CSS selector for the other image to make a new position for the new image. How can I go about renaming it in my index.html file so that I can so this? Here is a snippet of the HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
             <h1>Feed.me</h1>
          <img src="img/hat.png"></img>
          <img src="img/ware.png"></img>
```

And this is what it looks like in the CSS file:

```
img {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 595px;
z-index: -1;

}
```

Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look into [tag ids](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_syntax_id).

Comment: Did  you even try a google search or checked the css selectors before posting this..?

Comment: Yes, I did but was not able to find anything.

Comment: Why not use Bootstrap utilities (add a pull-left class on one and pull-right on the other)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use ids

i.e.

```
<div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
             <h1>Feed.me</h1>
          <img src="img/hat.png" id="image1"></img>
          <img src="img/ware.png" id="image2"></img>
```

Then

```
   #image1 {
     ...

   }
   #image2 {
     ...

   }
   img {
      .... common stuff
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a custom css class and assign it to the img. Like so:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <h1>Feed.me</h1>
  <img src="img/hat.png"></img>
 <img class="customImg" src="img/ware.png"></img>
```

CSS:

```
img {
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 595px;
z-index: -1;

}

.customImg{

position: absolute;
top: 5px;
left: 295px;
z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple of this...

1 - Set classes / ids to your images

```
<img class="left" src="img.jpg"/>
<img class="right" src="img.jpg"/>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    float: left;
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

2 - CSS selector `:nth-child`

```
img:nth-child(1) {
    float: left;
}
img:nth-child(2) {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using three different ways

1) apply `class` for the image tag

```
.image1_class

{
...
}

.image2_class
{
 ...
}
```

2)or apply `id` for the img tag

```
#image1
{
...
}
#image 2
{
...
}
```

3) if you dont want to add class or id , you can use `:first-child` or `nth-child()` selector in css

refer this link : [nth-child()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573159/how-to-select-first-img-tag-in-a-div-with-many-img-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest giving them separate ids so that you can adjust them individually such as:

```
<img src="/yourImages/image.jpg" id="img1" />
<img src="/yourImages/image.jpg" id="img2" />
```

And then in your css you can edit like this

```
#img1 { 
        Your styling here
}
#img2 {
        Your styling for the second image here
}
```

Dont know if this was what you were looking for but I hope it helps.

Comment: may i know what's the difference between [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24333361/2333214) posted 5 mins ago and yours..?

Comment: @Tilwin Joy lol I was surfing on my phone didn't see the other answers, when I noticed the question it had no answers tagged to it, I apologize for the redundancy, I guess from the time I found the question and the time I actually answered it my browser hadn't refreshed with the answers. Again my apologies.

Comment: no need for apologies i'm just another SO user. i was just wondering why you added the same answer again...